# How to split array to max length and loop over?

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, typescript, firebase

I am use Firebase for send push notification but get this error:

```
{ Error: tokens list must not contain more than 500 items
    at FirebaseMessagingError.FirebaseError [as constructor] (/srv/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/utils/error.js:42:28)
    at FirebaseMessagingError.PrefixedFirebaseError [as constructor] (/srv/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/utils/error.js:88:28)
    at new FirebaseMessagingError (/srv/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/utils/error.js:254:16)
    at Messaging.sendMulticast (/srv/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/messaging/messaging.js:297:19)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:229:7)
  errorInfo: 
   { code: 'messaging/invalid-argument',
     message: 'tokens list must not contain more than 500 items' },
  codePrefix: 'messaging' }
```

How I can split array and loop so I not get this error?

Answer (score 1):

The error message indicates that you're passing more than 500 tokens in a single call to the FCM send API. Since the maximum number of tokens that can be used in one call is 500, the API returns an error.

The solution is to pass in 500 or fewer tokens in the API call. If you need to send to more than 500 tokens, you will need to make multiple calls to the API.

Comment: Thanks for reply! Please you can give example of how we split token array and make multiple API call?